# Books / resources on measurement methods in atmospheric sciences

Tags: meteorology, measurements

I have found this very long book from weather.gov (free access)  [Guide to Meteorological Instruments and Methods of Observation](https://www.weather.gov/media/epz/mesonet/CWOP-WMO8.pdf) which might be a bit too in-depth for what I'm looking for, so I was wondering which other resources are available (bonus points for the ones with free access).

Comment: if you do a search for meteorology books free pdf you will find a lot of books,but as you know science books is often not exactly light reading.

Comment: I can find some meteorology books free online, but none of them actually has a chapter on measurement methods. Do you have any specific suggestion ?

Comment: sorry but no,some meteorological services have links on their webpages where one can find additional information.